# Time zone difference getting unexpected

Tags: windows, mfc

I am trying to get the time zone difference using windows API. I am using the code

```
    TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION TimeZoneInfo;
GetTimeZoneInformation( &TimeZoneInfo );
float TimeZoneDifference = -( float(TimeZoneInfo.Bias) / 60 );
```

I am using (UTC +5:30) time zone.

Output: 5.50000
Expected output: 5.30000

Comment: Half an hour is 0.5 hours.  Converting it to a HH:mm format is up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bias is in minutes ([Dev center Time zone info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

So a bias of +5:30, is 330 minutes.  Divide by 60 like in your code and you get : 5.5. A decimal representation of five and a half hours.

if you *insist* on getting 5.3, try:

```
float hours = trunc(float(TimeZoneInfo.Bias) / 60);
float nonDecimalHourFraction = float(TimeZoneInfo.Bias % 60) / 100;
float TimeZoneDifference = -(hours + nonDecimalHourFraction);
```

Comment: "%" left value must be int. when I have put as INT its output will be 6.0000. See the error "error C2296: '%' : illegal, left operand has type 'float'"

Comment: I don't have a compiler in front of me, but you'll need to make the bias an int (or long) but the result of the % needs to be a float again so that the divide by 100 gives a float result (0.3 instead of 1.0)

Comment: you did little bit to when we get the floor value of -5.5 is 6. So I modified the code as float hours = floor(-float(TimeZoneInfo.Bias) / 60);
float nonDecimalHourFraction = -float(TimeZoneInfo.Bias % 60) / 100;
float TimeZoneDifference = (hours + nonDecimalHourFraction);

Comment: Good call - because the bias was negative, my floor was acting as a ceil.  I've replaced it with trunc which should round towards zero and remove the trailing fraction regardless of sign.